# MySQL Join with denormalized join attribute

Tags: mysql, join, database-normalization

I need to perform a database join where unfortunately the database structure is not in the first normal form. I cannot change the table structure/layout because this is application generated and I can only create read-only queries to fetch data for my own statistic component.

The schema looks like the following. There is the table `services` which consists several attributes where especially the attribute `property` is relevant. The following are example rows of the `report` table:

```
table: report

id | vehicles | ...
-------------------
1  | 1,2,3    | ...
2  | 2,3      | ...
3  | 2        | ...
```

The `vehicle` tables looks like this:

```
table: vehicle

vid | description
---------------
1   | Vehicle A
2   | Vehicle B
3   | Vehicle C
```

My goal ist to count how often a vehicle was part of a report. The desired result rows are:

```
desired result

description | count(*)
----------------------
Vehicle A   | 1
Vehicle B   | 3
Vehicle C   | 2
```

The pseudo query for this would be something like:

```
SELECT v.description, Count(*)
FROM report r
JOIN vehicles v
ON v.vid IN(r.vehicles)
GROUP BY v.description;
```

Is there a MySQL way to handle this on the database side? Or do I have to select everything, explode the vehicles in the application login and perform the "join" outside the database?

I would prefer it to do this on the database side. I can only read both tables but can create views, if necessary (which I want to avoid, too, if possivle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that MySQL supports a `FIND_IN_SET` function where you can pass a string to search and a list to be searched.

Hence, a query which works is:

```
SELECT v.description as description, COUNT(*) as count
FROM report r
JOIN vehicles v
ON FIND_IN_SET(v.vid, r.vehicles)
GROUP BY (v.description);
```